# How to Implement auto round off to even number in a input field with Angular 4

Tags: angular

I've an input field in which any even number should be converted to nearest lower odd number. Plus, there should be 2 buttons to increment and decrement the value by 2.

Ex. If I enter 5, then number should be converted to 4 and should be replaced in the input field. I don't have any code so please don't down rank the question.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You must be looking for something like this:

In your **xyz.component.html**

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <button class="btn" (click)="quantity = quantity - 2"[disabled]="quantity == 0">minus</button>
    <input type="number" [value]="quantity" #quantitySelect (keyup)="roundOffQuantity(quantitySelect.value)" min="0" />
    <button class="btn" (click)="quantity = quantity + 2">plus</button>
</div>
```

In the **xyz.component.ts**

```
roundOffQuantity(value: number) {
    if (value % 2 != 0) {
        this.quantity = (2 * (Math.round(value / 2 - 0.01)));
    }
}
```